# RXjs emit a value to a subscriber before piping another value to the same subscriber

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to do the following:

```
observable.pipe(
  emit-value-to-subscriber(false),
  map((value) => doSomethingWithValue(value)),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Essentially intercept the value from observable and first emit a false value to the subscriber before piping the processed version of the value.

Is there a good way to do this in RXjs?  My current implementation just involves using two subscribers:

```
observable.pipe(
  map(() => false),
).subscribe(console.log);

observable.pipe(
  map((value) => doSomethingWithValue(value)),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

But I have serious doubts about the reliability of doing it this way (order of events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without `concat` and `startsWith` - if your want to handle a stream, e.g. `false, true, false, false, ...`, you will get a `false, %mod false%, true, %mod true% ...`.

```
Observable.from(false)
  .pipe(
    flatMap(x$ => from([x$, doSomethingWithAValue(x$)])),
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways of doing what you want.

Assuming `doSomethingWithValue` returns a boolean, you can use `startWith` operator:

```
observable.pipe(
  map((value) => doSomethingWithValue(value)),
  startWith(false),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

you can also use `concat`:

```
concat(
  of(false),
  observable.pipe(map(value => doSomethingWithValue(value)),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

you can also use `concat` inside `switchMap`:

```
observable.pipe(
  switchMap(value => concat(of(false), of(doSomethingWithValue(value)))),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

if there's a different observer, you can use `tap`:

```
observable.pipe(
  tap(_ => observer.next(false)),
  map((value) => doSomethingWithValue(value)),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear that this isn't a 'once off' observable, but on going values that must be interleaved with false, startWith wont cut it.